# What is the exact formula to calculate brute force password cracking time?

Tags: encryption, encryption-symmetric

Through my knowledge about this stuff, I've come up with a rough answer, but I'm in no way an expert and I want someone more knowledgeable to take a look and tell me if and where I'm wrong.

**Premise:**
We'll be using brute force against a completely random password that follows no known pattern and we'll assume we're using a symmetric encryption algorithm that has no known vulnerabilities, such as AES-256.

```
s: seconds to crack
c: length of the password in characters
p: hashes/s of the cracking machine
28: possible combinations for 1 byte
```

**My formula:**

```
    s = 28c ÷ p
```

It's very optimistic since not every single byte is mapped to a possible character, but other than that is the formula correct?

Answer (score 3):

This is basically correct, though it's probably better to think about it in the more general form:

```
total_time = total_hashes / hashes_per_time
```

And:

```
expected_time = total_time / 2
```

If you want to brute force a password (i.e. a thing that a user can type), then you need to think about the number of combinations of things that can be typed. On a US-style keyboard, that's roughly 96 characters, so for a maximum password length of `c`, total_hashes is `96^c + 96^(c-1) + 96^(c-2) + ...` (which is fairly well approximated by 96^c). If you want to brute lowercase-Latin, that `26^c + <smaller terms>`. If the thing you're brute force is an AES key, then there are 2 values per bit in the key and so brute forcing a 256-bit key is 2^256.

And for all linear searches, you are 50% likely to find the result after searching 50% of the space. So to find the "expected time," divide by two.

On the other hand, if you have just a little knowledge about what is likely (for example, users tend to use more Latin letters than symbols, password rules reduce the number of valid patterns, and it is generally more fruitful to search short passwords before long ones), you can organize your search and make your expected time shorter even if your total time doesn't change.

"Password" and "character" are also very broad terms. How many "characters" is 好 (if that's allowed)? Is it just one typed character or two UTF-16 bytes or three UTF-8 encoded bytes or four UTF-32 encoded bytes or something else? This matters a lot when deciding what "c" represents and what space you're searching. These kinds of questions are why I suggest thinking in terms of purely "total/rate". You can take the most conservative answer (256^b, where b is the total number of bytes, not characters), but this may be very inefficient for passwords.